# efficient way to invert a Matrix plus a diagonal one

Tags: matrices, covariance

Let $\Sigma$ be a $n \times n$ matrix, $V$ a $2 \times 2$ matrix and $I_{2 n}$ the identity matrix on dimension $2n \times 2n$. Both $\Sigma$ and $V$ are covariance matrices, thus real, symmetric and positive definite.

I need to calculate $(\Sigma\otimes V+\phi I_{2 n})^{-1}$ where $\phi$ is a positive scalar and $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product. How can I use the property of the Kronecker product to compute the inversion efficiently?

Comment: Thx. That could have an impact on possible approaches, so I took the liberty of editing your question to include this info. I'll delete my comment and suggest you do so, too, to clean up.

Comment: This might lead nowhere, but is a bit like evaluating 1/(1+x).  What happens if you expand in a Taylor series?

Comment: At least for the second term, it's a trivial special case of the [Sherman–Morrison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) formula for matrix inversion.

Comment: Do you need the result for pencil-paper work or for implementation in a statistical algorithm? For the latter case, you don't need to calculate the matrix inverse. It is no case known where a matrix inversion is inevitable.

Comment: I need it for a statistical algorithm....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may note that $\ker(\Sigma \otimes V + \phi I_{2n}) = \{0\}$ if and only if $\phi$ is not in the spectrum of $\Sigma \otimes V$.
It follows that $(\Sigma \otimes V + \phi I_{2n})$ is invertible if and only if $\phi $ is not an eigenvalue of $\Sigma \otimes V$. The spectrum of a Kronecker product of matrix is already studied and you can express it explicitly in termes of the spectrum of $A$ and the spectrum of $V$. [Here](http://orion.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/henry/reports/kronthesisschaecke04.pdf) it is shown that if $(\lambda,\sigma)$ and $(\mu,v)$ are two eigenpairs of $\Sigma$ and $V$ respectively, then $(\lambda\mu,\sigma \otimes v)$ is an eingenpair of $ \Sigma \otimes V$. Anyway in the link you should find some interesting factorization for solving efficitently the linear equation system $(\Sigma \otimes V + \phi I_{2n})x=b$. Computing the inverse directly is not very efficient except unless you need to solve this system a large amount of times for fixed $V$ and $\Sigma$ and varying $b$.